# Fit the image inside the carousel, cant seem to fix it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to fit the image inside the carousel, but I can't seem to fix it. Here is my css code:

```
   <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/Products/keyboard.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
          <h5 style="color:black">Welcome to LebShops</h5>
          <p style="color:black">Proud to be Lebanese</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/Products/mouse.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
          <h5 style="color:black">Enjoy our vast selection of products</h5>
          <p style="color:black">Cash on delivery</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/Products/airpods.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
          <h5 style="color:black">Whatever you need we got it !</h5>
          <p style="color:black">Cash on delivery</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

How can I fit my picture inside this carousel?
I've used css to adjust its height
I've checked other people's questions but it didnt help me.

Comment: Please attach the necessary stylesheet/CSS to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below snippet. I have used different size images in the gallery.

**The only change you need to add is css**

```css
img{
    object-fit: cover;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: none;
    height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/200/250" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
          <h5 style="color:black">Welcome to LebShops</h5>
          <p style="color:black">Proud to be Lebanese</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
          <h5 style="color:black">Enjoy our vast selection of products</h5>
          <p style="color:black">Cash on delivery</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/300/350" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
          <h5 style="color:black">Whatever you need we got it !</h5>
          <p style="color:black">Cash on delivery</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you want the image to fit then you may want to consider object-fit: contain rather than cover. Cover will fill the whole available space - cropping at top and bottom or at the sides as needed. Contain will make sure the whole mage is visible, which is normally what one wants in a carousel, even if there has to be empty space at top/bottom or at the sides.

Comment: of course, that can we a way to go. but if the image is too long to too wide you will end up having strange looking image. I prefer my images to be cover.

Comment: Yes, it depends on what is important for the particular images and use. If they all look OK even if cut off at the sides or top/bottom and there's nothing important in the bits that are cut off then it does look nicer having them all the same size - but if you are showing a gallery of artist's work all of which is different aspect ratios then you can't use cover - they would be upset!

Comment: Thank you Dhruvi your css helped me, although i made a little change. I've added an id to the images in the carousel so that the other images won't be affected. Thank you very much for your contribution <3